# VB.NET: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception

Tags: mysql

I don't know what may be wrong but that's what I get when I try to start the program:

The type initializer for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager` threw an exception.

The problem appears to come from `conn.Open()`

This is part of my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Main

Dim conn As MySqlConnection

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    conn = New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server='127.0.0.1';
    user id='root';
    Password='test';
    database='snipper'"

    Try
        conn.Open()

    Catch myerror As MySqlException

    End Try
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the problem... I hadn't enable "SQL Server Debugging". It worked well when I did. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How to enable SQL Server Debugging here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09x4a6at(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't make sense, if the problem is with the MySQL driver then why should SQL Server Debugging work ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with your connection string

For instance your connection string should be like this

```
Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

To know more [Click Here..!!!](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Hope this helps

Happy Coding

Comment: No, the connection string is ok actually. I forgot to mention that it was working some minutes ago. I don't know what happened!

Comment: can you check for the test connection?

Comment: The connection is proper. The strange thing is that if I run the exe file that is in the bin folder of the project, it works correctly.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html#downloads download the dll for mysql hope it helps

Comment: The dll was ok. I found and posted the solution yesterday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but a different solution. First I tried the enable "SQL Server Debugging", but that didn't change anything (I still don't know why this setting would make a difference).

The solution for me was the user rights on the server. The application runs with the Task Scheduler under a user account. Only the domain of this user account was changed. So the MySQL Connection didn't have enough rights.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure with that connection string?! Try to change it to:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=test;database=snipper;"
```

Follow this reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bad reference to the DLL. Make sure the dll is the right verson for the .net you're using. I also had the same issue and found that in the app.config file i was defining log4net configurations for my logger and that was the issue. i had to define a different config file for log4net so that mysql would work.