# How to fix Connection String error? con.Open() threw 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager'

Tags: c#, android, mysql, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm learning to make a connection to the local Mysql database from this link :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZ8HNJMXXg&list=WL&index=23&t=920s
and i get an error it said, 
"Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. occurred".

i have tried install Mysql.Data, MysqlConnector, Xamarin.Mysql.Data.
and can't solve my problem

i tried to switch Mysql.Data to Connector from this link,
[ReplicationManager threw an exception on opening a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737914/replicationmanager-threw-an-exception-on-opening-a-connection)
and still can't solve it and showing new error it said "try to add references/install nuget package for reference System.Memory..."

I have also searched Google, but I have not been able to resolve this error.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace App6
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private EditText _username;
        private EditText _password;
        private Button _insert;
        private TextView _syslog;  

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            _username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.username);
            _password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.password);
            _insert = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.insert);
            _syslog = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.syslog);

            _insert.Click += _insert_Click;
        }

        private void _insert_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //string connString = "Server = db4free.net; Port = 3306; database = db_nyube; User Id = naratama; Password = naratama123; charset = utf8";
            //MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            //MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;database=db_nyube;User Id=root;");
            //MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=db4free.net;user=naratama;database=db_nyube;port=3306;password=naratama123");
            string conStr = "Server = localhost; Database = db_nyube;  Uid = root; Pwd =;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = conStr;
            //MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Host = 127.0.0.1; UserName = root; Password =; Database = db_nyube;");
            try
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    _syslog.Text = "Sukses";
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                _syslog.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

i using Visual Studio 2017 Latest Version (15.9.15) and also Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03056

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: do NOT use localhost.  Use the IP address of your server

Comment: i have tried that.
127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.2

Comment: use the actual IP address of your server, not the loopback address

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not Xampp local server IP? when i open phpmyadmin and i saw server : 127.0.0.1 on top bar. am i wrong?

Comment: That is the loopback address.  Please read up on basic networking.

Comment: i really don't understand which IP you mean, but i have tried put my own PC (server) IP before and still not work.

Comment: this may not be the only problem you need to fix, but as a general rule you shouldn't use the loopback/localhost when dealing with mobile apps.

Comment: When it said "try to add references/install nuget package for reference System.Memory...", did you try adding a reference to that NuGet package?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger that is the problem, i don't know what package i shoukld install for reference System.Memory. I have read the bundles that will be installed when installing Mysql.Connector, it says System.memory.
so I have tried searching System.Memory in NuGET and Add References but could not find it.

Comment: @Gantama It's here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/
There's no dependencies listed for Xamarin.Android; I don't know if that's causing part of your problem or not.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger ah thanks, it's work. i just install System.Connector latest version from your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change Mysql.Data to Mysql.Connector and if Mysql.Connector error "reference appears to System.Memory", just install the latest System.Memory from this link : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/.

Thanks @BradleyGrainger