# How to solve the error message comes in vb.net mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an error when try to execute the following code.

The error is = "**The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception**".

I use Visual Studio 2019 & MySQL Server 5.7.
Help me to solve this error & thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub BtnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEnter.Click
    Dim server, user, password As String
    server = EdtServer.Text
    user = EdtUser.Text
    password = EdtPassword.Text

    Dim msb As MySqlConnectionStringBuilder = New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    msb.Server = server
    msb.Port = 3306
    msb.UserID = user
    msb.Password = password
    msb.Database = "test"

    Dim Con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(msb.ConnectionString)

    Try
        Con.Open()
        If (Con.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            MsgBox("Success !", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("UnSuccess !!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: can you see _what_ exception it threw? check if there's an `InnerException` property on the ex in your catch.

Comment: The type initialize for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.

Comment: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: are you sure you added the mysql dll to your program? else try the connectionsstirng without builder

Comment: Yes, I added the DLL file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773142/vb-net-the-type-initializer-for-mysql-data-mysqlclient-replication-replication) and are you sure you're using the correct version?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the unnecessary variables. You can assign your text box values directly to the msb properties as long as those properties are Strings.

Connections need to be closed and disposed. .Net languages provide Using...End Using blocks to accomplish this for us.

You don't need to check if the connection is open. If it fails to open, an exception will occur and the code will go directly to the Catch.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient 'At the top of the file

Private Sub BtnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEnter.Click
    Dim msb As MySqlConnectionStringBuilder = New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    msb.Server = EdtServer.Text
    msb.Port = 3306
    msb.UserID = EdtUser.Text
    msb.Password = EdtPassword.Text
    msb.Database = "test"
    Debug.Print(msb.ConnectionString) 'Will show up in the Immediate window
    Using Con As New MySqlConnection(msb.ConnectionString)
        Try
            Con.Open()
            MsgBox("Success !!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

There is nothing in the code you showed us involving `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager`. This error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I would say that your connection string is incorrect. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/